# How to do using java lambda stream:Given a list of students having books,find all student(s) reading the cheapest book(s)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am just trying to play around with lambda and stream .Say I have list of books domain having set of books. I want to find out student name who is reading cheapest book . I should be able to get the book with min price .I am able to get min price Book but how do I get student name ?

Edit: I updated as below. Is there any better way?

```java
    Supplier<List<Student>> studentListSupplier = () -> {
            return createStudentList2();
        };
        Book bookWithMinPrice=studentListSupplier.get().stream().flatMap(sl->sl.getBookSet().stream()).min(new BookComparator()).get();
        List<Student> studentsHavingbookWithMinPrice = new ArrayList<>();
        studentListSupplier.get().forEach(s->{
            if(s.getBookSet().contains(bookWithMinPrice)){
                studentsHavingbookWithMinPrice.add(s);
            }

        });


class Student {
    private String name;
    private Set<Book> bookSet;
    ////
}

class Book {
    int price;
    String name;
    ////  
}
 //DataSet
private static List<Student> createStudentList2() {
        Set<Book> bookSet1 =   new HashSet<>();
        Book b11=new Book(10, "AAA");
        bookSet1.add(b11);
        Book b12= new Book(20, "BBB");
        bookSet1.add(b12);

        Set<Book> bookSet2 =   new HashSet<>();
        Book b21=new Book(30, "XXX");
        bookSet2.add(b21);
        Book b22= new Book(15, "ZZZ");
        bookSet2.add(b22);
        Book b23 =  new Book(10, "KKA");
        bookSet2.add(b23);

        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.setBookSet(bookSet1);
        s1.setName("s1");

        Student s2 = new Student();
        s2.setBookSet(bookSet2);
        s2.setName("s2");

        Student s3 = new Student();
        s3.setBookSet(bookSet1);
        s3.setName("s3");

        List<Student> studentListWithBooks = Arrays.asList(s1,s2,s3);
        return studentListWithBooks;
    }
```

Comment: What are you looking for? Find the lowest price across all books, then list the students who has a book with that price? Or for each student, find the cheapest book they have? Or for each book (by name), find the cheapest price of that book, then list the students who has the book for that price?

Comment: So having find the cheapest price book, can I find the student who had that book? Or is there an alternate way..Code snippet please..

Comment: Which part is troubling you? Iterating all students? Iterating all books? Finding the lowest price? Finding students who have a book with that price? Please make your own attempt. You'll learn a lot for that way. If you can't figure out how to do it with stream, try doing it with `for` loops first.

Comment: Ok:)  Found out. we have to iterate over list then check i nset with contains .Will update.  But is there any better way?

Comment: *"check with contains"*??? Why would you do that? --- *"any better way?"* Better than what? You haven't shown your full solution.

Comment: Sorry  for the confusion. I updated in my original post.

Comment: So, you need all students reading the cheapest book? Or only one of them?

Comment: All student**s** *(plural)* reading the cheapest book**s** *(plural)*. OPs solution misses on the book**s** part.

Comment: Yeah, probably.

Comment: @Andreas Yes this wording is correct. I will update the heading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Student studentWithCheapestBook = students.stream()
    .min(comparingInt(s -> Collections.min(s.getBookSet(), comparingInt(Book::getPrice)).getPrice()))
    .orElse(null);
```

`Collectors.comparingInt` as a static import.

Instead of `comparingInt(Book::getPrice)` you could also use your `BookComparator`. :)

If you need all students, then you cannot do it with one stream. You need to compute the cheapest price first, and then filter the list of students accordingly.

```
int cheapestPrice = students.stream()
    .flatMap(s -> s.getBookSet().stream())
    .mapToInt(Book::getPrice)
    .min().orElse(0);

Set<Student> readingCheapestBooks = students.stream()
    .collect(filtering(s -> s.getBookSet().stream().anyMatch(b -> b.getPrice() <= cheapestPrice), 
             toSet()));
```

I just found out that since Java 9 there is a `Collectors.filtering`. :)

Comment: I will checkout your solution. I updated my attempt above.

Comment: What if there is more than one student with a book at lowest price?

Comment: @VivekMisra What is there is more than one book with minimum price? E.g. John has "Landscaping for Dummies" at $0.50, and Steve has "Gardening for Dummies" at $0.50. Shouldn't they both be returned? You have to compare *prices*, not *books*, which is why I was initially confused when you mentioned using `contains`.

Comment: I think my code already finds the cheapest price book first.
Edit:Yes if there are more than one book with min price, then it will increase complexity. I am not sure of simple solution with less complexity.

Comment: The first solution isn't good for performance, since it may call `Collections.min` multiple times for the same student.

Answer (score 1):

To find all students *(plural)* reading the cheapest books *(plural)*, you first need to find the cheapest *price*, then find students that have a book at that price.

```
int minPrice = students.stream()
        .flatMap(s -> s.getBookSet().stream())
        .mapToInt(Book::getPrice)
        .min().orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
List<Student> studentsHavingBookWithMinPrice = students.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.getBookSet().stream().anyMatch(b -> b.getPrice() == minPrice))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` ensures an empty result list if there are no books. Better than `getAsInt()` which would throw exception if there are no books.

Comment: Accepting. But if there are more than 1 book with same cheap price, we will need to modify.

Comment: @VivekMisra It doesn't really matter whether or not there is one or multiple books having the cheapest price. The approach works either way.

Comment: @Michael Then why does the code  gives me result that only student s1 and s3 have cheapest book. If you see dataset, all three s1,s2 and s3 have cheapest book with price 10. ( I have updated OP and added dataset). And it should also get me 2 books with cheapest price 10  .

Comment: @VivekMisra Using which solution? I am referring to the approach outlined in this answer and my own answer. Then you get back s1, s2 and s3.

Comment: @Michael I was testing Andreas answer. I see you updated your answer and your answer correctly identifies all 3 students . It is better approach then looping (my original solution).

Comment: @VivekMisra Don't know what your problem was with my code, but it returns all 3 students from your dataset. See [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/LxDdwt) for proof.

Comment: @Andreas  I might have used wrong data for your solution while trying out different datasets. It returns correctly now. Both attempts by you and Michael are fine and almost same. (But only one can get accepted :) )